# R/RStudio set keyboard shortcuts using script/code

Tags: r, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'll now be working between a Mac and a PC using R/RStudio for the projects. I've got a series of keyboard shortcuts (pipe, assignment operator) for each machine using keys that are conveniently located. The two computers don't have the same keyboards.

I'd like to create a script that I can run that tells R/RStudio to change all keyboard shortcuts to `x` or `y`? My question is: Can keyboard shortcuts be set using code in scripts or the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation :

The RStudio keybindings are saved as JSON files in the directory ~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/ -- you can find the bindings for the editor and RStudio itself at:

```
~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/rstudio_commands.json
~/.R/rstudio/keybindings/editor_commands.json
```

I think you can make a script that edit json then restart R